# Get DaoSession en proyecto de libreria

Tags: android, greendao

Buen dia Saludos a todos, actualmente estoy usando aprendiendo a usar greendao 3, he leido varios tutoriales y en todos los ejemplos usan greendao dentro de una app, en cambio yo estoy implementandolo en un proyecto de libreria, mi pregunta es como obtener el DaoSesssion en un proyecto de libreria, por que para hacerlo en los ejemplos hacen lo siguiente:

```
DaoSession daoSession = ((App) getApplication()).getDaoSession();
```

y en una libreria no puedo usar la función getApplication.

Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mi solucion, aunque no se en realidad si es muy optima, fue no depender de Application, porque una app android solo puede tener una Application class declarado en el manifest de la app principal donde se ejecute la libreria. por lo tanto decidi crear una clase con el patron singleton  y de ahi llamar cuando sea necesario a DaoSession. les dejo el codigo por si les sirve, o si pueden mejorarlo.

Esta es la clase:

```
    public class DaoHelper {

private static volatile DaoHelper daoInstance;
private DaoSession daoSession;

private DaoHelper(Context context){
    //Prevent form the reflection api
    if(daoInstance!=null){
        throw new RuntimeException("Use getInstance() method to get the single instance of this class.");
    }else{
        CustomDaoMaster.OpenHelper helper = new CustomDaoMaster.OpenHelper(context,
                "db",null);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        CustomDaoMaster daoMaster = new CustomDaoMaster(db);
        daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
    }
}

public static DaoHelper getInstance(Context context){
    //Double check locking pattern
    if(daoInstance==null){
        synchronized (DaoHelper.class){//Check for the second time.
            //if there is no instance available... create new one
            if(daoInstance==null)daoInstance = new DaoHelper(context);
        }
    }

    return daoInstance;
}

public DaoSession getDaoSession(){
    return daoSession;
}
```

y esta la forma de usarla:

```
DaoSession daoSession = DaoHelper.getInstance(context).getDaoSession();
```